# What converts mechanical energy into kinetic energy? Would it be a generator or a motor?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

I know that mechanical energy is the sum of an object's potential and kinetic energy. Also know that a turbine (mechanical energy) coverts into electrical energy by use of a generator. So is electrical energy considered kinetic?

Answer (score 1):

An electric generator converts mechanical energy into electrical energy. An electric motor converts electrical energy into mechanical energy. Note that these are not necessarily separate devices - some devices can act as either electric generators or electric motors, depending on how they are configured.

The term mechanical energy is used here to refer to both kinetic energy and potential energy because it is easy to convert from one to the other, and so sometimes not useful to distinguish between them. For example, a hydroelectric generator uses the kinetic energy of running water to produce electrical energy. But you can also say that it uses the potential energy difference between water in a high reservoir and water at a lower level.

Another word for motor is engine. As well as electric motors there are many other types of motors or engines. Steam engines, petrol engines, diesel engines, jet engines and rocket engines all convert the chemical energy stored in their various fuels into mechanical energy.

Answer (score 0):

No, electrical energy is not considered kinetic . A generator

> [a device that converts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_generator) motive power (mechanical energy) into electrical power for use in an external circuit.

A motor

> [is a machine designed to convert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engine) one or more forms of energy into mechanical energy

In general, energy is conserved from one system to another , but it has different forms in different systems.